# Netflix/Amazon Video keeps stuttering

Tags: video, netflix

I keep getting stuttering whenever I want to watch Netflix/Amazon Prime Video and I have had this problem since I recently installed Windows on my new Samsung SSD. I have tried:

- Updating AND Reinstalling my AMD drivers
- Using different browsers (Chrome, Opera, Epic and Edge)
- Disabling 2/3 of my screens (Which slowed the stuttering a VERY small bit i think)
- Restarting several times
- Changing my resolution (No noticeable difference)

It stutters every 1.5/2 ish seconds and when i disable all but one of my monitors it stutters every 3 ish seconds.

I have: i5-4590, 4GB SAPPHIRE AMD R9 380, 16GB DDR3 RAM and Windows 10 (updated max)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot :)

Comment: I have the EXACT same issue. I decided to try and play a new series from amazon last night and same thing, it stutters every 2 seconds and the mouse damn near freezes as well. I am in IT, so I tried almost everything. Finally, convinced it was something wrong with Windows 7, I installed Windows 10 with a clean install (deleted partition first), and installed fresh new drivers for my R9 380, fresh install of Chrome and FireFox, same issue. Still stutters every 2 seconds. I have tried to revert back to a previous graphics driver, but it's the same issue. I'm not sure if it's the samsung ssd or t

Comment: So is that your using a Samsung SSD too? @Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found its really common for the AMD gfx cards, How I fixed my issue is by fully uninstalling AMD panel and then the driver in device manager and then re-install. DO NOT use the AMD Auto-detect as I have found this is what was causing me my issues. Select your card manually and all should work fine :)

Hope this helps :)